# C# How would I write a utility that updates the IP address across multiple config files in different folders

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration

I have a software that upon installation asks for the IP address of my server and stores that address into multiple config files in different folders.

What I'm trying to do is create a utility where if for whatever reason my IP address were to change the IP address that was stored will update to the current IP address.

My code is simply just telling me my local IP Address but it's not updating the IP address inside the config file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConfigTool
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static IPAddress GetIPAddress(string hostName)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            var replay = ping.Send(hostName);

            if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return replay.Address;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Local IP Address: " + 
            GetIPAddress(Dns.GetHostName()));
            Console.WriteLine("Google IP:" + GetIPAddress("google.com"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<endpoint name="???Local" address="net.tcp://122.13.0.250:7732/EventSubscriberServices/Secure" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="************" bindingConfiguration="TcpCustomSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
```

Comment: Give sample of xml file.  There a number of different Net Libraries that can be used to read and write xml.

Comment: Are you talking about updating config files that are generated for .Net applications?  If so, you'll also need to consider restarting all the applications that you've updated, because if they're running and you change the config they won't see the change.  It would make more sense to have a central location that all your applications read from, and they read every time they need the value so you just have to update that 1 place.  (DB or WebApi is ideal for this, depending on the scenario.)

Comment: I made edits and added sample of xml file containing IP address.

Comment: You have no code writing to any config files, how do you expect the config files to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement endpoint = doc.Descendants("endpoint").FirstOrDefault();

            string newIp = "122.13.0.251";
            string address = (string)endpoint.Attribute("address");

            string pattern = "//[^:]+";
            address = Regex.Replace(address, pattern, "//" + newIp);

            endpoint.Attribute("address").SetValue(address);
            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works but I don't want the file path to be hard coded. When a user downloads the software I want the code to look where the software has been installed and run and use an Environment Variable as a default location like Program x86.

Comment: Modify as needed.